# Nodejs Mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a movie site. In watch video I want to show all below data.

1. In video collection I want to get

   - All fields by id.(Have foreign key stars_ID)
   - Top 10 most watch video of the week.
   - 20 movie by same star
   - 20 movie by same category.
2. In stars collection  I want to get [name, profile_image]
3. In comment collection I want to get all fields where parent_id = video_id

**My current solution:**

I get all data

```
// watch
app.get('/watch/:id', function(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
    videoMdl.getvideoById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('video/views/watch',{
            title:data.title, 
            data:data,
        })

    })

})

// get video by id
module.exports.getvideoById = function(id, callback){
    videosModel.findById(id, callback);
}
```

As you can see I only get data from video collection by id.
To get others data I use Angularjs which is bad for SEO that's why I dont like and looking for better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
// get cast
    function getTopCast(req, res, next){
        castMdl.findTop({}, function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            req.topCast = data;
            next();
        })
    }
    // get Video id
    function getVideoId(req, res, next){
    var id = req.params.id;
            videoMdl.getvideoById(id, function(err, data){
                if(err) throw err;
                req.video = data;
                next();
            })


    }
    // render
    function renderData(req, res, next){
        res.json({video:req.video, cast: req.topCast});
    }
    app.get('/xem/:id', getTopCast,getVideoId, renderData);
```